# Database schema for web dashboard confusion

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to make web application which allows users to monitor their websites data in real time dashboard. But now am confused a bit how to store data, for good website performance. I would like to use Microsoft SQL Server database engine, with entity framework. So I made a sketch of database, I was thinking to use:
[image]

But now am confused about performance of this type of data storing. All I need that user can have many dashboards, with infinitive numbers of widgets on them, also they could share their dashboard with others. Also sorting widgets by category then selecting them into dashboard. My point is, maybe someone could share their opinion about database schema, is it relevant for project like, that and if not how could I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pre-mature optimization. Do you have millions of users? Probably not. Right now all that is important is laying out the data in a way that is sensible to the development team. Does this data make sense to you based on how you plan to use it? If the answer is yes then keep this schema. It is difficult to know what your app will be like in a year's time and impossible to know about a time when you will require optimization.

Right now you have 4 tables so you don't need to worry about the connectivity of your data. As long  as you understand your data you will be fine.b